# postgres partition number

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that is partitoned on time field. I have 25 partitions. Now I consider partitioning it further more using object type field. I have ten object types so it will result in 250 partitions. According to what I read, the recommended partition number is few dozens but in my cases the schema is very simple and doesn't include any joins so I wonder if it's o.k. to define that many partitions. I am using postgres version 9.1.2

```
CREATE TABLE metric_store.lc_aggregated_data_master_10_minutes
(
  from_time integer,
 object_id integer,
 object_type integer,
 latencies_client_fetch_sec_sum bigint,
 latencies_client_rttsec_sum bigint,
 latencies_db_bci_res_sec_sum bigint,
 latencies_net_infrastructure_ttlb_sec_sum bigint,
 latencies_retransmissions_sec_sum bigint,
 latencies_ttfbsec_sum bigint,
 latencies_ttlbsec_sum bigint,
 latencies_ttlbsec_sumsqr bigint,
 latencies_ttlbsec_histogram_level0 integer,
 latencies_ttlbsec_histogram_level1 integer,
 latencies_ttlbsec_histogram_level2 integer,
 latencies_ttlbsec_histogram_level3 integer,
 latencies_ttlbsec_histogram_level4 integer,
 latencies_ttlbsec_histogram_level5 integer,
 latencies_ttlbsec_histogram_level6 integer,
 latencies_ttlbsec_histogram_level7 integer,
 usage_bytes_total bigint,
 usage_hits_total integer,
 latencies_server_net_ttlbsec_sum bigint,
 latencies_server_rttsec_sum bigint,
 avaiability_errors_total integer
)
  WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
  );
  ALTER TABLE metric_store.lc_aggregated_data_master_10_minutes
  OWNER TO postgres;


CREATE TABLE metric_store.lc_aggregated_data_10_minutes_from_1353070800
(
  CONSTRAINT lc_aggregated_data_10_minutes_from_1353070800_pkey PRIMARY KEY (from_time , object_id ),
  CONSTRAINT lc_aggregated_data_10_minutes_from_1353070800_from_time_check CHECK (from_time >=      1353070800 AND from_time < 1353190800)
   )
    INHERITS (metric_store.lc_aggregated_data_master_10_minutes)
   WITH (
   OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE metric_store.lc_aggregated_data_10_minutes_from_1353070800
OWNER TO postgres;


CREATE INDEX lc_aggregated_data_10_minutes_from_1353070800_obj_typ_idx
ON metric_store.lc_aggregated_data_10_minutes_from_1353070800
USING btree
(from_time , object_type );
```

Comment: How many rows? Are you sure queries of the unpartitioned table are as good as they can be? (Partitions are a poor substitute for good indexing.) Is faster hardware a better solution? (Partitions are a poor substitute for an adequate server, too.)

Comment: it's about 10 million rows. I have index on the object type but queries over many object ids for over 100  time points are very slow becuase of many random access seeks to the disk.  breaking the data to smaller partition yields performance improvment becuase I usually query for the same object types in a query.

Comment: 10 million rows isn't a huge table. If I were you, I'd seek advice on tuning the unpartitioned table first. Also, version 9.2 has index-only scans, but I don't think that will help you here.

Comment: The slow query already uses the relevant index (from time + object id) so I don't know which other improvment can be done here.I checked the index only scan in postgres 9.2, but the problem here is that it only works after vacum analyze and each change to the table requires running the vacum again. the latest partition will have inserts every 10 minutes so running vacum each 10 minutes time isn't feasible option.

Comment: Did you consider [partial indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-partial.html) or [indexing on an expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-expressional.html), [multi-column indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-multicolumn.html), or [splitting multi-column indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-bitmap-scans.html), changing cost estimates or statistics parameters? I don't have 9.2 installed yet, but it seems odd that you'd have to vacuum analyze a partitioned table after each change.

Answer (score 1):

The current version (9.2) has this [guidance about the number of partitions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-partitioning.html). (That guidance hasn't changed since 8.3.)

> All constraints on all partitions of the master table are examined
>   during constraint exclusion, so large numbers of partitions are likely
>   to increase query planning time considerably. Partitioning using these
>   techniques will work well with up to perhaps a hundred partitions;
>   don't try to use many thousands of partitions.

From reading the PostgreSQL mailing lists, I believe increasing the time for query planning is the main problem you face.

If your partitions can segregate hot data from cold data, or if your partitions can group clustered sets of data you frequently query, you will probably be ok.  But testing is your best bet. `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` representative queries in the unpartitioned table, then do the same after partitioning.  Choose representative queries before you analyze any of them.

Comment: what do you mean by segregate hot data from cold data ? , does the schema complexity has any impact on the query planner calculation complexity ? becuase in my case the scheam is very simple without any  queries that require joins.

Comment: Timestamps are often queried on "current" or "recent" data, and less often (maybe rarely) queried on data more than a month old or more than a year old. "Current" or "recent" data is hot (frequently queried) data; data more than month or year old is cold (rarely queried) data. Id's can also have hot and cold subsets of data. A schema that requires many joins increases the work the query planner has to do, but the time planning the joins would usually be dwarfed by the time optimizing access to a thousand partitions. (Because the planner examines every constraint on every partition.)